# UINavgationController and UITabBarController together

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to create a view with a TableView in the center, NavigationBar on top, and a TabBar with 5 items.  The TabBarItems will be attached to 5 different modal views.  And the tableview can select an item and "navigate" to another tableview or detail view.

Following the Apple doc, I tried to create a NavigationController in a TabBarController in IB, but failed.  I read all the posting regarding to this topic, and they all described a NavigationController inside one of the TabBarItem.  But that is not what I want.  The TabBarController and NavigationController are separate controller doing separate thing in the same view.

So I start wondering maybe it is a design issue.  I should just use a NavigationController and add the TabBar as objects and not controller in the view.

Am I going the right track or is there a better way to combine NavigationController and TabBarController in IB to do the job that I want.  Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the tab bar is actually being used as a tab bar, it sounds like you want 5 navigation controllers, one for each tab.

If the tab bar is being used as a toolbar to hold buttons that bring up modal view controllers, push views onto the navigation controller, or other actions besides what a tab bar is intended for, use a UIToolbar instead. UINavigationController actually has toolbar support built in, just set its `toolbarHidden` property to NO and set the `toolbarItems` property on each view controller that can go inside the navigation controller to an array of appropriate UIBarButtonItems.

Comment: Ah, so I did design it wrong.  I don't want 5 navigation controllers. But is it ok to use the TabBar?  Because I do like the TabBar look more than the toolbar...  I hope there is nothing in Apple's HIG for that. 

Thanks!!

Comment: [The HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW74) does say not to use a tab bar for controls that act on the current screen, and they have a blanket statement that controls should "behave as they do in [Apple's] applications".